# ReactJS logic: Return 8 to 8 links and fill empty places with images

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have links rendered dynamically with ReactJS and I would like to follow this logic: I want to return 8 to 8 groups and fill the empty space with images like that:

```
<a>Content</a> <!--1-->
<a>Content</a> <!--2-->
<a>Content</a> <!--3-->
<a>Content</a> <!--4-->
<a>Content</a> <!--5-->
<a>Content</a> <!--6-->
<a>Content</a> <!--7-->
<a>Content</a> <!--8-->
<a>Content</a> <!--1-->
<a>Content</a> <!--2-->
<a>Content</a> <!--3-->
<a>Content</a> <!--4-->
<a>Content</a> <!--5-->
<img src="square.jpg"/> <!--6-->
<img src="square.jpg"/> <!--7-->
<img src="square.jpg"/> <!--8-->
```

The division of each 8 link groups will be made by pagination and it isn't the purppose yet; I'm foccused only to fill the empty spaces.

Here is the part of my component React code that is used to render the dynamic HTML:

```
return (
      <div>          
        {this.state.interiores.map(item =>
          <div>
            <div className="gallery">
              {
                item.fotos
                  .map((foto) => {
                    return (
                      <a href={`../images/${foto}.jpg`} className="big">
                        <img src={`../images/${foto}_thumb.jpg`} alt="" />
                      </a>
                    )
                  })
              }
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
    )
```

How can I solve it? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that, while JSX tags **look** like html, they are compiled to regular old js objects. You can simply create the array, and then fill it with the buffer images if less than size 8. E.g.

```
renderFoto = (foto) => {
  return (
    <a href={`../images/${foto}.jpg`} className="big" key={foto}>
      <img src={`../images/${foto}_thumb.jpg`} alt="" />
    </a>
  )
}

renderBufferImage = (index) => {
  const key = `placeholder${fotos.length}`
  return <img src={'square.jpg'} key={key} />
}

renderItem = item => {
  // make an array of all the fotos
  const fotos = item.fotos.map(this.renderFoto)
  // add buffer images until filled to 8
  while (fotos.length < this.pageSize) {
    fotos.push(this.renderBufferImage(fotos.length))
  }
  // render the array inside a div
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="gallery">{fotos}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

render = () => {
  return <div>{this.state.interiores.map(this.renderItem)}</div>
}
```